# Best way to iterate through a list of objects, to grab attributes

Tags: java, spring-boot

What's the best way to create a new list of attributes from an existing list of objects, if certain attributes values exist? Should I convert the list to a map? But then I'd want the list attributes to be the Map key and I don't know how to grab the attributes.

Should I just iterate through this list, and if one of the attributes to the list has a value, add that attribute to a new list, or is there a faster or better way to achieve what I am trying for?

I need this new list to create a table with dynamic headers.

```html
List<CommissionSchedule> commissionSched = commissionScheduleRepository.findByCarrier(carrier);
     
List <String> hs= new ArrayList<>();
for (CommissionSchedule cs: commissionSched){
    if (cs.getCategory()!=null){
        hs.add("Category");
    } else if (cs.getAutoNew()!null){
       hs.add("Auto New");
    }
    //...etc

}
```

this than just doing a bunch of if/ else if cases for each attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not add an assessor in the CommissionSchedule class ?

```
String getHs(){
    return  category !=null ?  "Category":
            autoNew !=null ? "Auto New" :
            "others" ; 
}
```

then in the loop, you just need to call getHs() method

using streams would be something like this.

```
List<CommissionSchedule> commissionSched = 
    commissionScheduleRepository.findByCarrier(carrier);

List<String> hs = commisionSched.stream()
                        .map(cs -> cs.getHs())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

alternatively, you can do it like this

```
List <String> hs= new ArrayList<>();
for (CommissionSchedule cs: commissionSched){
    hs.add(cs.getHs());  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Reflection API like :

```
    UnaryOperator<String> capitalize = s -> s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
    for (Field att : CommissionSchedule .class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        Method getter = CommissionSchedule .class.getDeclaredMethod(String.format("get%s", capitalize.apply(att.getName())));
        if (getter.invoke(b1) != null) {
            hs.add(att.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

This is available if your class is a Bean. You can use utilities API to manipulate your beans like BeanUtils.